# Why HHVM (zend-compat mode) doesn't free object's memory?

Tags: php, zend-framework, hhvm

An object in PHP extension has 3 main handlers: create, destroy and free.

The "create" handler is assigned here (see comment "HERE"):

```
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(test2)
{
    zend_class_entry tmp_ce;
    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(tmp_ce, "Test", test_functions);
    test_ce = zend_register_internal_class(&tmp_ce TSRMLS_CC);

    test_ce->create_object = my_create_handler; // HERE

    memcpy(&test_object_handlers, zend_get_std_object_handlers(), sizeof(zend_object_handlers));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The remaining 2 handlers is assined in the `my_create_handler`:

```
zend_object_value my_create_handler(zend_class_entry *class_type TSRMLS_DC)
{
    test_object *intern = emalloc(sizeof(test_object));
    memset(intern, 0, sizeof(test_object));

    zend_object_std_init(&intern->std, class_type TSRMLS_CC);
    object_properties_init(&intern->std, class_type);

    retval.handle = zend_objects_store_put(
        intern,
        (zend_objects_store_dtor_t) my_destroy_handler,       // DESTROY
        (zend_objects_free_object_storage_t) my_free_handler, // FREE
         NULL TSRMLS_CC
     );


     retval.handlers = &test_object_handlers;
     return retval;
}
```

I build and run my extension for PHP5, PHP7 and HHVM (zend-compat mode). In my `test.php` I do

```
<?php
    $o = new Test();
    $o->myMethod();
?>
```

The difference between PHP5, 7 and HHVM is:

- PHP5 calls `create` and `free`;
- PHP7 calls `create`, `destroy`, `free`
- HHVM calls `create` and memory does leak.

Why HHVM (run with `-m daemon`) does not call `free`? I suspect it could use some optimizations, reusing created objects in other requests, but after million of requests the objects keep creating.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in HHVM. You should [file an issue about it](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues).